# StringIndexer in Spark MLlib

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have a column of nominal values in my `PipelinedRDD` that I would like to convert to index encoding for classification purposes.

I used to use the `StringIndexer` in `pyspark.ml` which was extremely easy to use. However, this time I am learning how to deal with rdd instead of a dataframe, and there isn't such a thing in `pyspark.mllib`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: String Indexer is not available for RDD based API. But why do you want to use it for RDD, when Dataframe is faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `StringIndexer` in the Spark MLlib, so you need to do the work yourself. Start by collecting all possible values for that column and assign each a number, save this as a dictionary. Afterwards, apply it on the original rdd values.

The code below is assuming that `PipelinedRDD` contains two values for each row, with the value to convert in the first position (0):

```
dic = PipelinedRDD.map(lambda x: x[0]).distinct().zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
PipelinedRDD = PipelinedRDD.map(lambda x: (dic[x[0]], x[1]))
```

**Note**: This differs slightly from the Spark implementation of `StringIndexer` since it does not take into account the frequency of the values (Spark will assign 0 to the value that appears most, then 1 and so on). However, in most cases what index different strings are assign is of no concern.

---

**Extension**
If you want to mimic exactly what the StringIndexer does, as mentioned in the note above, the code can be slightly modified to take that into consideration

```
dic = PiplelinedRDD.groupBy('cat_column').count().sort(col("count").desc()).map(lambda x: x[0]).zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
PipelinedRDD = PipelinedRDD.map(lambda x: (dic[x[0]], x[1]))
```

Comment: String Indexer uses the frequency distribution before indexing the string variables ? Why did you reject the edit

Comment: @pratiklodha: I prefer a simpler solution since in most cases which index is assigned to which strings are not of interest (added a note to the answer regarding it). However, maybe it can be added as an extension to the answer or as a new answer.